# jQAssistant - reduce memory consumption

Tags: java, nexus, jqassistant

We have a Nexus repository with some thousand artifacts - jars, war and ears. I tried to scan this repository with jQAssistant (using `scan -u maven:repository:...`), but even 4GB of heap memory for Java 1.7 were not enough, an out of memory error occured after some hours.

Is there a way to reduce the memory consumption, e.g. scanning the repository in parts? Or can I configure jQAssistant to use less memory?

Answer (score 1):

The repository scanner has been tested with a quite large set of artifacts running for hours, so this is a bad surprise.

It would be helpful to see the cause of the problem. Can you do the same run with

```
JQASSISTANT_OPTS=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError ...
```

load the generated dump with Eclipse MAT (http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) and create a leak suspects report (that's one of the options offered directly after loading the dump)?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I hope to see some results tomorrow.

Comment: To give an intermediate result: When I set the heap memory to 8GB, it worked, using up to about 7GB. Unfortunately, memory profiling with JVisualVM kills the program (it would have been interesting).

Comment: Just a question: Does your repository contain large archives containing other archives (like distribution ZIPs with EAR files in them)?

Comment: The repository does contain some large ear files, with <100 jars in them.